# database schema creation with the use of liquibase at spring does not work

Tags: java, database, postgresql, spring-boot, liquibase

in spring boot version below 2.5.0 I had this configuration in application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb?currentSchema=myschema
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
spring.liquibase.default-schema=myschema
spring.liquibase.liquibase-schema=myschema
```

additionally, in the schema.sql file I had such a query to create a schema in the database:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS myschema;
```

while in spring boot from 2.5.0 the configuration field:

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

should be replaced with:

```
spring.sql.init.mode=always
```

unfortunately, after applying these changes from version 2.5.0, the liquibase solution does not work as expected and the database schema is not created. What is it caused or how can it be dealt with?

the errors that appear are:

```
2022-10-13 15:34:18.741  INFO 28767 --- [           main] liquibase.database                       : Set default schema name to null
2022-10-13 15:34:18.748  WARN 28767 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.LockException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: no schema has been selected to create in
  Pozycja: 14 [Failed SQL: (0) CREATE TABLE databasechangeloglock (ID INTEGER NOT NULL, LOCKED BOOLEAN NOT NULL, LOCKGRANTED TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, LOCKEDBY VARCHAR(255), CONSTRAINT databasechangeloglock_pkey PRIMARY KEY (ID))]
```

or

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.LockException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: schema "myschema" does not exist
  Pozycja: 14 [Failed SQL: (0) CREATE TABLE myschema.databasechangeloglock (ID INTEGER NOT NULL, LOCKED BOOLEAN NOT NULL, LOCKGRANTED TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, LOCKEDBY VARCHAR(255), CONSTRAINT databasechangeloglock_pkey PRIMARY KEY (ID))]
```

The only solution I came up with was to turn off liqibase during the first start of the application, then the schema is created normally, but I would like to get help, how can I solve it differently?

Comment: Why do you need both schema.sql and liquibase? They cover the same functionality, with liquibase obviously being more powerful.

Comment: Have you tried manually creating databasechangeloglock ?

Comment: I want to use schema.sql before using liquibase, because if I have default-schema and liquibase-schema configured in the application.properties, even if I have changeset to create the database schema, then when starting the application I will first throw an error that the configuration schema database does not exist. Unless you can somehow create another database schema through liqiubase before starting it?

Comment: I have the same problem with schema creation

Answer (score 0):

So your aim is to create the pre-requisites for Liquibase itself? i.e. the database schema where Liquibase lives?

The first thing to realize is that Liquibase (or Flyway) doesn't play well with other DDL mechanisms offered in the Spring stack. This includes, but not limited to,:

- [Spring Boot DataSource initalization using Basic SQL scripts](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization.using-basic-sql-scripts)  (this is the one you mention)
- JPA (or Hibernate) DDL mechanism

The reason for this is order of execution. You cannot guarantee which one fires first.

[Pre-Liquibase](https://github.com/lbruun/Pre-Liquibase) to the rescue. It was designed for this exact purpose.

Step 1: Add a dependency like this to your project.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.lbruun.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>preliquibase-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version> <!-- exact version would depend on which version of Spring Boot you're using -->
</dependency>
```

Step 2:
Now add a file called `default.sql` to `src/main/resources/preliquibase/` with content like:

```sql
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS ${spring.liquibase.default-schema};
```

Step 3:
Enjoy.

Full disclaimer: I'm the author of Pre-Liquibase. If you don't like bringing in an additional dependency then feel free to view the code of what is does. Some people use Pre-Liquibase solely as a `test` dependency. Some people use it in production. Pre-Liquibase only plays a role during startup of your application.